# Edit an applescript file from a linux computer

Tags: linux, macos, applescript

Though applescript appears to be a scripting language like any other ([wikipedia/applescript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript)), for reasons I don't understand it seems these scripts are often saved as *binaries*. It seems like this isn't an issue for someone working on a Mac with a mac-based text editor that can open these scripts into a plain-text format where they can be edited and read, but for the rest of us, we just see gibberish. For instance, Github has many examples of .scpt files committed to repositories instead of/without the plain-text equivalent (a bit of Googling suggests this would be a `.applescript` file instead)

**Question**: Is there an open-source tool that can parse and serialize these binaries so that they can be viewed/edited in a standard plain text editor and saved back as `.scpt`?

(My context: I'd like to provide a user-friendly, os native button-click way to launch my application on a mac, rather than tell users to open a bash terminal and type stuff.)

**Edit** I only have access to a linux machine, I don't own a mac.

Comment: If someone wants to downvote this question, perhaps they could provide some context as to why?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/163134/why-are-script-editor-scpt-files-not-saved-as-plain-text-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to create an AppleScript on a non-Mac, what you can do is simply name your shell script file with a .command suffix and make sure that it has execute POSIX permissions for the user. The user can then double-click the file in the Finder to execute your script instead of having to enter Terminal commands.

If you would like to take advantage of AppleScript commands within your shell script file to add some simple GUI functionality, you can use the [osascript command](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/osascript.1.html).

BTW, for reference: on a Mac the application "Script Editor" (or "AppleScript Editor" on older systems) is generally used to create AppleScripts. It provides several save options - the .scpt binary and .applescript plain text files you noted as well as .scptd script bundles and .app standard, double-clickable applications.

Comment: This answer does give me more background on the Mac, which is useful in general, so thanks for the reference.  The shell script with `.command` extension and osascript could work, but it would be useful to be able to modify the existing applescript directly.

Comment: You need not only a Mac but every application the script uses must be installed as well. Apple event messages represent all command/parameter/etc names as ints, not strings. AppleScript relies on scriptable applications to provide "dictionaries" that map these ints (aka "four-char-codes") to/from human-readable keywords. `.scpt` files contain AppleScript bytecode which uses only four-char-codes, so to convert that bytecode back to readable source code (`.applescript` files) requires all the original app dictionaries plus something that understands AS's undocumented bytecode format. IOWURSOOL.

Comment: @foo thanks for the explanation, that is a good technical answer as to why such a tool cannot exist.

Comment: @foo how is TextMate 2 able to open a `.scpt` file perfectly? (TextEdit, Xcode, etc. cannot).